# Unity2D - Counter wont count killed enemys

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I tried adding a counter that counts the enemys that have been killed by the player. The problem is that the counter wont go  up no matter what I do. Heres the code. I created a Text field on my UI canvas.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemyCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxScore;
    public float Score = 0;
    public Text ScoreText;


    void start()
    {
        Score = 0;
    }

    public void AddScore(int newScore)
    {
        Score = + newScore;
    }
    public void UpdateScore()
    {
        ScoreText.text = "Töte 3 slimes:" + Score;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UpdateScore();
    }
}
```

Then I implemented the AddScore method into my TakeDamage method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SlimeHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxHealth;
    private Animator anim;
    public float currentHealth;
    public HealthBarSlime healthBar;
    public static event Action OnEnemyDeath;
    public EnemyCounter score;


    private void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
       
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        healthBar = GetComponentInChildren<HealthBarSlime>();   
    }




    void Update()
    {

        if (maxHealth < currentHealth)
        {
            currentHealth = maxHealth;
            anim.SetTrigger("hurt");
        }
            

        if (maxHealth <= 0)
        {
            
            anim.SetBool("die", true);
            Destroy(gameObject);
            

        }

    }


    void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;

        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {


            score.AddScore(1);
            if (OnEnemyDeath != null)
            {
                OnEnemyDeath.Invoke();
                
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I tried putting the "score.AddScore" in the Update method but it also didnt work.

Comment: Syntax problem, it should be `Score += newScore`, not Score = + newScore